# The underlying connection was closed sharepoint online executequery

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

Techies,

Below is the code and receiving the error "The underlying connection was closed" only in my VM not in another Virtual Machine

This is console application

```
string decryptedPass = "password";

        System.Security.SecureString securePass = new System.Security.SecureString();
        foreach (char c in decryptedPass)
        {
            securePass.AppendChar(c);
        }

        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("siteurl");
        SharePointOnlineCredentials credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("emailid", securePass);
        List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("listname");
        clientContext.Credentials = credentials;
        ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
        ListItem oListItem = oList.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
        oListItem["Title"] = "Test Item!";
        clientContext.RequestTimeout = 100000;

        oListItem.Update();

        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: thank you very much..
working as expected for me...

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. Feedback should be given through comments or in Chat.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/95235)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this to beginning of your code:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Or change .Net Framework to 4.6

The issue related to default TLS settings of a web request.